# Scrape only rows with today's date from table

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm not able to filter the  results of `table[3]` to only include rows that have today's date in them. I'm using this url as my data source:

http://tides.mobilegeographics.com/locations/3881.html

I can get all the data back, but my filtering isn't working. I get the entire range, 5 days back. I only want something like this: (current day)

```
Montauk Point, Long Island Sound, New York
41.0717° N, 71.8567° W

2014-03-13 12:37 PM EDT   0.13 feet  Low Tide
2014-03-13  6:51 PM EDT   Sunset
2014-03-13  7:13 PM EDT   2.30 feet  High Tide
```

How can I get this and then calculate if the tide is moving in/out within next 40 minutes.

Thanks for helping.

**My Code is:**

```
import sre, urllib2, sys, BaseHTTPServer, datetime, re, time, pprint, smtplib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.diagnose import diagnose

data = urllib2.urlopen('http://tides.mobilegeographics.com/locations/3881.html').read()
day = datetime.date.today().day
month = datetime.date.today().month

year = datetime.date.today().year
date = datetime.date.today()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

keyinfo = soup.find_all('h2')
str_date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
time_text = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 20)

t_day = time_text.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
tide_table = soup.find_all('table')[3]
pre = tide_table.findAll('pre')

dailytide = []
pattern = str_date
allmatches = re.findall(r'pattern', pre)
print allmatches

if allmatches:
    print allmatches
else:
    print "Match for " + str_date + " not found in data string \n" + datah
```

Comment: Kindly post your code as well. Also, re: send an e-mail, start a new thread for that one afterwards. That's an entirely different issue from the one you're asking for.

Comment: Also, just tested it on my end. The best approach will be to just get the table completely, and use string manipulation on it. Hint: `.splitlines()` and `.startswith()` will be your best friends. :)

Comment: No problem. Let us know if you encounter difficulties setting this up.

Comment: Edit your original post and post your code there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression, just split the contents of a `pre` tag and check if today's date is in the line:

```
import urllib2
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'http://tides.mobilegeographics.com/locations/3881.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL))
pre = soup.find_all('table')[3].find('pre').text

today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
for line in pre.split('\n'):
    if today in line:
        print line
```

prints:

```
2014-03-13  6:52 PM EDT   Sunset
2014-03-13  7:13 PM EDT   2.30 feet  High Tide
```

Comment: Gosh, simple. THANK YOU!
Can you recommend a good site to explain this for the not-so-swift?

Comment: @user3416214 well, besides [official documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), check the BS [popular answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup?sort=votes&pageSize=50) here on SO. Also, consider accepting the answer if you think it deserves. Thanks.